# Could wizards have provided muggles with endless energy?

Tags: harry-potter

In the third book when Harry is in Lupin's office, Lupin brought a kettle to the boil with a tap of his wand. Given that most of our means of energy-production is by turning water into steam to power a turbine, does this mean that wizards were sitting on a source of endless energy? Seeing as how most of our wars are over resources, sharing this could've stopped a lot of wars.

I guess it boils down to how this magic works. **Was there boiling water somewhere else which was teleported into the kettle (like food is "created")? Or was the water boiled via magic (thus allowing for the premise of this question)?**

Comment: q.v. Legend of Korra, where Firebenders are running power stations that supply steam-generated electricity

Comment: No, because doing so would violate the laws that prevent Muggle/Wizard contact.

Comment: Imagine prostitutes using *Polyjuice Potion* to become Taylor Swift. Wizards can rule the muggle world without violence or mind control.

Comment: Note that free energy is not necessarily the same as infinite or unlimited energy.

Comment: This seems to be a perfectly factual question.

Comment: I don't think we can answer this question with the Harry Potter canon. While it is clear that the water was boiled via magic, it raises another question... Is magic an infinite resource?

Comment: Big difference between boiling a kettle and running a power station turbine. Free energy may not scale up to industrial levels.

Comment: @Alex - I fail to see how this could be answered without masses of opinion-based guesswork. Can a wizard boil water endlessly? Can they boil industrial-sized amounts of water? Would they be willing to do so? Would the Ministry of Magic be willing to allow them to do so? Is magic endlessly available? Etc etc

Comment: Of course this is provided that the miggle/wizard secrecy was not in place. Like practically, could it be done?

Comment: @Valorum Not knowing the answer doesn’t mean that there is no answer. Just like every character has a birthday even if we may not know it, the water was either boiled via magic or it wasn’t. Magic can either provide endless energy or it can’t. If you don’t know the answer, don’t post guesses; rather, let someone else who does know the answer post it. If you are confident that there is no available information with which to answer the question, then post *that* as the answer.

Comment: @Alex - The problem is that I do know the answer (thanks for asking), but that the answer is "in my opinion xyz" which means that my answer is basically worthless, as is the question that spawned it.

Comment: @Valorum “in my opinion xyz” is not the correct answer, though. Just like it wouldn’t be the correct answer if the question had been “what is Bob Ogden’s birthday?”

Comment: @Alex - Sure, but the question here isn't "*What is Bob Ogden’s birthday?*", it's "*What would Bob Ogden like for his birthday?*"

Comment: @Valorum That’s answerable in the same way. We may or may not know what he wants, but there is still factually something that he wants. For minor characters we will probably have limited information about that, and therefore the Stack Exchange answer will likely be that we don’t know what he wants. But for major characters there might be some information. For instance, Dumbledore complains about receiving books instead of socks for Christmas. Slughorn talks about the gifts his students send him. Etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Endless, yes. Limitless, no.  Useful, Maybe.**

I don't think there is a definite canonical answer but my opinion is that Lupin boiled the water by instantly adding energy.  Hermione made a fire in a jar to warm her friends, so why not?

There are also examples of objects being conjured out of either nothing or "thin air", which from a Muggle science perspective sounds a lot like creating energy.

Magic itself is limited - some spells require several magic users to work together, and Dumbledore told Harry that the amount of magic in an individual is finite and can be measured.  On the other hand there is at least one "permanent" energy-producing spell, "eternal fire", which is said to burn forever. Maybe the magic channels energy from another source, or maybe that finite bit of magic can produce infinite energy.

Either way, the amount of *power* available seems to be limited - it might burn forever (infinite energy) but it produces heat at a limited rate (finite power).

It's likely that a sufficiently powerful witch/wizard could provide enough eternal fire to run a small Muggle turbine.  There is probably a more efficient way of doing it, the likely problem is the relatively small population of magic users.  There might be only a few individuals in each generation that can make a long-term energy spell, the spell might take a long time to prepare and it might only provide a relatively small amount of power.  If the energy-producing spells truly last forever then enough generations of wizards might eventually overtake the Muggles' power requirements, but it might take a while (especially if Muggle gadget makers think they have free power to work with) and wizards and Muggles don't always play well together.

Also, as [Valorum](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/20774/valorum) pointed out, it would be a breach of the International Statute of Secrecy so some kind of legal fudge would be needed to let it happen.

There is another unknown factor here:  It is stated that certain things can't be conjured, and aside from "good food" we aren't told what they are.  There is a chance that "large amounts of useful energy" is also on the list.

Comment: And of course it would be a total violation of the law to do so.

Comment: Yes it would, but exceptions can be applied to the Statute of Secrecy, so I imagine it could be done here if it was considered important enough.   For example, Hermione's parents were allowed to change money at Gringott's, and the Muggle Prime Minister was given updates in person by a wizard (heralded by a wizard painting that he couldn't get rid of).